# Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, jvm, malloc, heap-memory

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1048576 bytes for AllocateHeap

   # An error report file with more information is saved as:
   # C:\jboss-eap-services-6.4.4\bin\hs_err_pid6632.log
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; 
  support was removed in 8.0
```

With the problem above, I'm trying to start the jboss server. I tried some steps and I could not find the right solution.

Comment: "I tried some steps" is a pretty pointless information. Tell us what you tried, otherwise people might quickly recommend things that you tired already!

Comment: And beyond that: try putting error messages into search engines. There are quite some resources that give exactly the same answer you just accepted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following setting to allocate the memory for the permanent location `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

Comment: There is no sense in specifying `-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` when the log posted in the question clearly says that this is Java 8 and these options are unsupported and ignored. Further, there is no recognizable reason for specifying `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase eclipse memory, you can do this in le eclipse.ini file (near eclipse executable file) or in the command line arguments :
-Xms256m
-Xmx16348m

Answer (score 1):

It is JBoss (not Eclipse) that is crashing.  So increasing Eclipse's memory is futile!  (It might make things worse, in fact.)

The second thing to note is that you are running out of space in a native allocation request, so increasing the regular heap's size will not help.  Options like the following will probably NOT help!  (They might make things worse, in fact.)

```
 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit     # USELESS
```

The third thing to note is that your JVM doesn't have a PermGen space, so fiddling with the PermGen size via

```
 -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m          # USELESS
```

is futile.  (That is what `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0` is saying.)

---

So what is the real problem?

Well you are running a 64-bit JRE, so it is not an architectural problem.  (On a 32-bit JRE, the JVM's address space has hard limits ...)

In fact, it is a problem outside of the JVM itself.  Basically, the JVM has asked the OS for more memory, and the OS has said "Nope!".  I can thing of two possible explanations:

1. There may be a per-process "ulimit" in place, that is restricting the process size.  Your JVM has requested beyond that limit.
2. The OS may have run out of virtual address space or mappable virtual memory.  The former is unlikely.  The latter typically arises because your OS doesn't have enough RAM and/or swap space.  This can also happen is you are running within a virtual machine that is ... less than generous endowed with memory resources.

Now it appears that this may be happening when the JVM is trying to grow the Java heap.  But either way, the problem is not the size of the Java heap.